# Properly setting Nginx for handling blocks to handle Angular website

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm having problem to setup my Angular website using Nginx in AWS instance. My server.conf format is below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location /server/ {
        proxy_pass         http://internal-xxxxxxxx-12345678.eu-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/;
    }

    location / {
        root /home/ubuntu/project/dist/anglr;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

To give a brief, I'm hosing my angular website in one instance and I've a server hosted in another instance (handled by a load balancer). To access my server API the URL format is 'http://mywebsite.com/server/xxxxx'. When my Nginx receives this URL, it has to redirect to my api-server instance. My home page of the website is working good, api-server is also working good.
The problem is that when it has to refresh the angular page like 'http://mywebsite.com/hobbies', its throwing 404.
I didn't understand what am I missing in my Nginx conf file to handle url like 'http://mywebsite.com/hobbies'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike normal static files websites, angular uses it's own internal routing. In a normal web server, when a user accesses a url, e.g. `/category/productA.html`, the web server looks under category directory and tries to serve productA.html.

However, in the case of Angular, when the web server receives a request to `/hobbies` it tries to look for the directory `/hobbies`. However, the web server wouldn't find it which then prompted it to correctly throw a HTTP 404 error.

I believe you can fix this error by changing your nginx config file:

```
server{
   ...
   root /home/ubuntu/project/dist/anglr;
   ...

   location /{
      try_files $uri$args $uri/args/ /index.html
   }
}
```

This will prompt nginx to serve index.html file again on 404 and angular will perform it's internal routing.